# is it ok to resign and tell your employer the Job is not a fit

Tags: resignation, employer, probation

I have just passed probation at my current job after 6 months. I don't really get on with the team, there have been no fights or anything, but the chemistry is not there.

I'm miserable in the job and had a lukewarm probationary meeting which I passed and was made permanent about 2 weeks ago.

I have been offered another job and have accepted it. I will need a reference from my current job and don't want to burn bridges.
I feel I cant lie and say "I'm moving for personal reasons", it wont make sense, as I didn't mention it at the probation meeting. I want to tell my boss that "I'm leaving as I don't feel I fit into the role as I thought I would" I'm worried he will ask why and the why is the answer I cant come up with. I'm lost, I don't want to point fingers or accuse, especially as my boss is one of the people I would point fingers at if I had to. I need help?

I need to know how to answer the question of "why it isn't a fit?" without stating that its because of you and "the poor chemistry I have with the team".

I also want to know if stating the fact that "I don't fit into the job as well as I thought I would" is a career damaging statement ?

Comment: Sorry I was just ranting and stressed when I wrote this. Hopefully its better.

Comment: @jean2211 I still think you can improve your post. What is it your goal you want to achieve? Do you want us to help you phrase such answer in a professional way so you don't burn bridges? You may want to make that stand out in your phrasing.

Comment: I'm one of those people who almost always advises people to be honest in workplace situations. But in this case, the honest answer will reflect badly on you. Even though it may not be your fault at all, your boss will probably think it is (you didn't like working for such an awesome boss and his hand-picked superstars). So my advice would be to come up with an answer that is not a lie but that is not overly descriptive either. Whatever version of the truth you think will get you the best recommendation, essentially.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so are you saying I shouldn't say "I don't feel like I have fit into the role as I thought I would"?

Comment: If you already accepted the job offer sounds like you don’t actually need a reference from your current employer.   Don’t burn bridges if there are only a few bridges in your town and/or field.

Comment: @jean2211 Yes, that's what I'm saying. He may hear that as you having unrealistic expectations or not wanting to do hard work. Perhaps you can say something more along the lines of getting an unexpected opportunity for career advancement. Stress how unexpectedly good the alternative is, not how unexpectedly bad this job is.

Comment: @Ramhound it a conditional offer, its based on pre employment checks etc, which includes references, current employer included. My other 2 references are really good, I'm just worried that they could blow up my chances, or create a situation where I walk in to the next job with raised eye brows, meaning I have to double up on proving myself.

Comment: @DarkCygnus , yes I need help in phrasing my answer if  I'm further questioned. I don't want to burn bridges, or have them give a poor reference or no reference at all.  My appraisal was lukewarm already, which is why I don't see the point in lying and saying its just personal reasons.  I also, want to know if admitting that "the job is not a fit for me " is bad to say to an employer?

Answer (score 2):

You can resign for any reason, and you don't *need* to give a reason to the employer. You could just say it's for career progression.